# I am new to JavaFX. I want help on how to make a TreeView node Draggable and Droppable

Tags: java, treeview

I know this question has been asked a multiple times, but I was unable to get help from any of the article.

My Main.FXML is

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <TreeView fx:id="treeView" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="24.0" onContextMenuRequested="#mouseClick" onMouseClicked="#mouseClick" prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="493.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My Controller.java is

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable
{
    @FXML TreeView<String> treeView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("root");

        TreeItem<String> nodeA = new TreeItem<>("nodeA");
        TreeItem<String> nodeB = new TreeItem<>("nodeB");
        TreeItem<String> nodeC = new TreeItem<>("nodeC");

        root.getChildren().add(nodeA);
        root.getChildren().add(nodeB);
        root.getChildren().add(nodeC);

        treeView.setRoot(root);

        root.setExpanded(true);
    }

    @FXML
    private void mouseClick(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        TreeItem<String> item = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(item.getValue());
    }
}
```

My Main.java is

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have seen article that teaches how to add the Drag and Drop feature to TreeItem via TreeCell by adding Cell Property. But the processes were quiet complicated and I being a layman to JavaFX was unable to understand those.

So, it will be quite helpful if anyone can help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your Controller code responsible for setting a custom cell factory, that will attach handlers to Drag/MouseEvents.

```java
treeView.setCellFactory(param -> {
    // creating cell from deafult factory
    TreeCell<String> treeCell = TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView().call(param);
    // setting handlers
    treeCell.setOnDragDetected(this::onDragDetected);
    treeCell.setOnDragOver(this::onDragOver);
    treeCell.setOnDragDropped(this::onDragDropped);
    return treeCell;
});
```

Basic handlers taken from [DragEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/DragEvent.html) javadoc page:

```
private void onDragDetected(MouseEvent event) {
    TreeCell<String> source = (TreeCell<String>) event.getSource();
    Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putString(source.getItem());
    db.setContent(content);
    event.consume();
}

private void onDragOver(DragEvent dragEvent) {
    Dragboard db = dragEvent.getDragboard();
    if (db.hasString()) {
        dragEvent.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
    }
    dragEvent.consume();
}

private void onDragDropped(DragEvent event) {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    boolean success = false;
    if (db.hasString()) {
        System.out.println("Dropped: " + db.getString());
        success = true;
    }
    event.setDropCompleted(success);
    event.consume();
}
```

Comment: I want one more help on this topic. I want to get the node name printed in the console on which dragging is done and the name of the node on which the source node is dropped. In short i want the source and target node's name. Thanks in advance

Comment: use:
(TreeCell<String>) dragEvent.[getSourceGesture()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/DragEvent.html#getGestureSource--) to get access to your TreeCell. For target node is the same only method name is getTargetGesture

Comment: I have tried the way you said but I am facing two problems :

Comment: Problem No. 1 : I used System.out.println((TreeCell<String>) dragEvent.getSourceGesture()).Here the Output was : "TextFieldTreeCell@fff603[styleClass=cell indexed-cell tree-cell text-field-tree-cell]'nodeB'",     Problem No. 2: I also used System.out.println(((TreeCell<String>)dragEvent.getGestureTarget()).getText());  Here in the output : Only onDragDetected is active no DragOver nor DragDropped is active.

Comment: 1. TreeCell has getItem method, which returns type-value in this case String "nodeB",    
2. DragOver/Dropped might be not active, when you don't put anything in Dragboard or put null in drag detected handler.

Comment: TreeCell<String> cell = (TreeCell<String>)dragEvent.getGestureTarget();
        String item = cell.getItem(); System.out.println(item); , it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @kozmatteo I was able to acquire the drag and drop feature of TreeView in JavaFX. The Controller code is as below :

**Controller.java**

---

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.input.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable
{
    @FXML TreeView<String> treeView;
    private TreeCell<String> source, treeCell;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("root");

        TreeItem<String> nodeA = new TreeItem<>("nodeA");
        TreeItem<String> nodeB = new TreeItem<>("nodeB");
        TreeItem<String> nodeC = new TreeItem<>("nodeC");

        root.getChildren().add(nodeA);
        root.getChildren().add(nodeB);
        root.getChildren().add(nodeC);

        treeView.setRoot(root);

        root.setExpanded(true);

        treeView.setCellFactory(param -> {
            // creating cell from deafult factory
            treeCell = TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView().call(param);
            // setting handlers
            treeCell.setOnDragDetected(this::onDragDetected);
            treeCell.setOnDragOver(this::onDragOver);
            treeCell.setOnDragDropped(this::onDragDropped);
            return treeCell;
        });
    }

    private void onDragDetected(MouseEvent event)
    {
        source = (TreeCell<String>) event.getSource();
        Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(source.getItem());
        db.setContent(content);
        System.out.println("Dragging: " + db.getString());
        event.consume();
    }

    private void onDragOver(DragEvent dragEvent)
    {
        Dragboard db = dragEvent.getDragboard();

        if (db.hasString())
        {
            dragEvent.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
        }

        dragEvent.consume();
    }

    private void onDragDropped(DragEvent event)
    {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        String targetNode = ((TreeCell<String>)event.getGestureTarget()).getItem();

        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasString()
                && !targetNode.equalsIgnoreCase(source.getItem()))
        {
            System.out.println("Dropped on: " + targetNode);
            success = true;
        }
        event.setDropCompleted(success);
        event.consume();
    }
}
```

Demonstration for the code above:

[image]

---

But One of the problem that occurs if the `onDragOver` code is changed a bit. I want to print the name of the node upon which the dragging node is dragged over.

`onDragOver();` method changed:

---

```
private void onDragOver(DragEvent dragEvent)
    {
        Dragboard db = dragEvent.getDragboard();
        if (db.hasString())
        {
            dragEvent.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            String targetNode = ((TreeCell<String>)event.getGestureTarget()).getItem(); // On adding this piece of code the DragOver event is not working.
        }

        dragEvent.consume();
}
```

Demonstration after adding the code above:

[image]

**Finally:**

I want to know the name of the node on which the source is being dragged over. If anyone can help me with this then it will be very much helpful.